# Word interop PDF/A type export

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, office-interop, export-to-pdf

I would like to export PDF/A type from Word document. Like if I woud go Export> Create PDF/XPS> Options > Tick PDF/A Compilant.
Right now I have working code:

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($@"{docPath2}\{InputBox}.PDF", Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

But how can I define a Type of PDF? Or it is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **useUseISO19005_1: true** like this:

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($@"{docPath2}\{InputBox}.PDF", Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF OpenAfterExport: true, UseISO19005_1: true);
```